# Is using null to declare literal members for later initialization a viable praxis in JS?

Tags: javascript, null, literals, object-literal, member-initialization

I'm going to declare a literal as follows:

```
var obj = {
    x: null,
    init: function (pX) {
        this.x = pX;
    }
};
```

Objections?

I'd like to do that because `x: undefined` would be the same as not declaring `x` at all. Whats a good practice when declaring literal members for later initialization?

Comment: @Tomalak Someday I'll know what I was thinking when I wrote that, but not today.

Comment: Creating a property with an `undefined` value is not the same as not creating the property.

Comment: @Bergi i know its been a while, but can u explain the difference?

Comment: @sirrk: The difference is the existence of the property. They might yield the same when accessed (as non-existing properties return `undefined`), but tests like `in` or `.hasOwnProperty` show the difference clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the property to exist as a placeholder for some reason, `null` is as good a value as any. You can use any value that is different enough from what it's going to contain when initialised, and that is comparable.

Example:

```
var obj = {
  x: null,
  init: function (pX) {
    if (this.x == null) {
      this.x = pX;
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't need to check the value of the placeholder (or for some other odd reason), then you don't need the placeholder either. It's perfectly valid to create the property by assigning a value to it:

```
var obj = {
  init: function (pX) {
    this.x = pX;
  }
}
```

Comment: Someday I'll know what I was thinking when I wrote that, but not today.

Comment: @Guffa declaring the property by assigning a value to it through a function makes it very hard to read. The property should be declared where all the others are declared.

Comment: @sirrk: If you only want the property declared for documentation, then any value would do. Using `undefined` would be a fine way to show that the property is declared, but that it doesn't have any usable value yet.

Comment: ..but its not exactly undefined, but unassigned. I now feel like im free to use `null`, but i wonder if that implies something for others reading my code wich im not aware of. I read a lot about JS lately, but dont remember anyone using `null` at all. maybe it comes down to opinion in this particular case, maybe i didnt ask the right question, so i'll mark your answer as accepted. though it wasnt quite what i wanted to hear.

Comment: @sirrk: If you want to declare the property, then you can't have it unassigned, it has to have a value. The `null` value is used for pointers in other languages, so you could use it to hint that the property should contain an object, and use `undefined` for plain values. If you are going to assign a value to the property in the initialisation anyway, then it's only for documentation purposes. If a value like `null` or `undefined` isn't enough, then you can just add a comment.